# TFS API to create a TFS Group and set permissions?

Tags: api, tfs

Hello I'm trying to use TFS API to create a new group, for it I have this code:

```
var teamProjects = this.VersionControlServer.GetAllTeamProjects(false);
foreach (var teamProject in teamProjects)
{
     var result = _gss.CreateApplicationGroup(teamProject.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri, "NewGroup","TestDescription");

     //NOW I WANT TO SET THE PERMISSIONS FOR THIS GROUP
}
```

As I need to set the permission "Edit project-level information" for this group I tried lot of methods and different approaches, but anything seems to solve my need. This for example:

```
var ProjectSecurityToken = AuthorizationSecurityConstants.ProjectSecurityPrefix + teamProject.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri;
var groupACL = securityNamespace.QueryAccessControlList(ProjectSecurityToken, new[] {list[4].Descriptor}, false);

securityNamespace.SetAccessControlEntry(ProjectSecurityToken, new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.AccessControlEntry(list[4].Descriptor, 115, 0), true);
```

I had hard-coded "list[4]" because it was the group I just created, I need some help to see what is wrong in my code. I get no error message and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: In my opinion, TFSSecurity command line is easier than TFS API to add permissions for a user or a group in a server-level, collection-level, or project-level group. You may consider using TFSSecurity command line: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#aplus

Comment: TFSSecurity worked fine! But the API approach is a bit better. 

I'm looking for a way to deny workitem customization for project administrators, is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the permissions been set via following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace API
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string project = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(project));
            var tps = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var ttt = tps.GetTeamProject("ProjectName");
            ISecurityService securityService = tpc.GetService<ISecurityService>();
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityNamespace> securityNamespaces = securityService.GetSecurityNamespaces();
            IGroupSecurityService gss = tpc.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
            Identity SIDS = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "GroupName", QueryMembership.Expanded);//GourName format: [ProjectName]\\GourpName
            IdentityDescriptor id = new IdentityDescriptor("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity", SIDS.Sid);
            List<SecurityNamespace> securityList = securityNamespaces.ToList<SecurityNamespace>();
            string securityToken;
            foreach (SecurityNamespace sn in securityList)
            {
                if (sn.Description.DisplayName == "Project")
                {
                    securityToken = "$PROJECT:" + ttt.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri;
                    sn.SetPermissions(securityToken, id, 115, 0, true);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working as expected! Awesome! 
I used the enumerator instead the integer directly: 
sn.SetPermissions(securityToken, id, 0, TeamProjectPermissions.AllPermissions, true);


Is there a way to get "Create tag definition" set as well? It's the only permission not set using this code.

Comment: @Fabito See this link: http://roadtoalm.com/2014/07/28/add-permissions-with-tfssecuritythe-ultimate-reference/

Comment: seems in the link saying to use the namespace "Tagging" but it doesn't exist, also I didn't find any reference in MSDN or some Microsoft website. :(

Comment: Know how to set area-level permissions instead of project-level permissions using API from a console application? All posted blogs/answers, _that I've managed to come across after days of research_, referring to area-level permissions are outdated.