# Windows Service connecting to TFS. IGroupSecurityService instance creation fails with no exception

Tags: c#, windows, service, tfs

I have a running service installed on a Windows 2012 R2 server that is trying to connect to a TFS instance.

After turning on remote debugging and looking at the code I noticed the section below which had a breakpoint set. As soon as I clicked step into at the first line, the debugger behaves as though I clicked continue, I exit my step through and the debugger claims the code is continuing. There is no exception thrown.

This code is being called every five minute by a service timer, I think that the code called by the timer never completes, after the first line it experiences some kind of crash. 
Five minutes later, the code tries to run again, so I know it has not crashed the entire service.

I have looked at the event view, there is not information there.

```
IGroupSecurityService gss = (IGroupSecurityService)TfsConfiguration._tfsProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IGroupSecurityService));
Identity SIDS = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "Project Collection Valid Users", QueryMembership.Expanded);
List<Identity> FoundIds = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, SIDS.Members, QueryMembership.None).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640524/tfs-api-to-create-a-tfs-group-and-set-permissions) case:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace API
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string project = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(project));
            var tps = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var ttt = tps.GetTeamProject("ProjectName");
            ISecurityService securityService = tpc.GetService<ISecurityService>();
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityNamespace> securityNamespaces = securityService.GetSecurityNamespaces();
            IGroupSecurityService gss = tpc.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
            Identity SIDS = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "GroupName", QueryMembership.Expanded);//GourName format: [ProjectName]\\GourpName
            IdentityDescriptor id = new IdentityDescriptor("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity", SIDS.Sid);
            List<SecurityNamespace> securityList = securityNamespaces.ToList<SecurityNamespace>();
            string securityToken;
            foreach (SecurityNamespace sn in securityList)
            {
                if (sn.Description.DisplayName == "Project")
                {
                    securityToken = "$PROJECT:" + ttt.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri;
                    sn.SetPermissions(securityToken, id, 115, 0, true);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions ended up being way off base. This is not the source of the problems.... I'll post in another question the real case. This has been an two week issue now, apologies for the waste of a question here.