# How Set version control permission in a Team Project for a group in a C# class?

Tags: c#, tfs

[version-control-permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHJy8.jpg)

Hi!

I want to develop a method in my C# application in order to set version control permission in a team project for a group: for example I would like to set the "menage permission" to Allow.

The Image I added is the same feature I want, using the TFS web app.

I searched also in the TFS documentation, but I found only a tf permission command line way...
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TFSSecurity` command line is much easier than TFS API to add permissions for a user or a group in a server-level, collection-level, project-level, or a git repository. You may consider using `TFSSecurity` command line, for more details, here is a  decent documentation on MSDN: [Change groups and permissions with TFSSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-QmRPCpFAizwyL48jk5y3IQ&tduid=(6e3fdbcf37c491d323069e82827d2dad)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-QmRPCpFAizwyL48jk5y3IQ)())

For using TFS API, you need to get the guid for the security namespace to be used in the `GetSecurityNamespace` method, then set the permission. Below is a related code:

```
// Get the TFS security service.
var sec = tfs.GetService<ISecurityService>();
SecurityNamespace sn = sec.GetSecurityNamespace(FrameworkSecurity.TeamProjectNamespaceId);
string securityToken;
if (sn.Description.DisplayName == "Project")
{
   securityToken = "$PROJECT:" + projectUri;
   sn.SetPermissions(securityToken, newGroup, TeamProjectPermissions.AllPermissions, 0, true);
}
```

For more detail info you could have a look at below related question and blog:

- [TFS API to create a TFS Group and set permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640524/tfs-api-to-create-a-tfs-group-and-set-permissions)
- [Add permissions with TFSSecurity–The ultimate reference](https://roadtoalm.com/2014/07/28/add-permissions-with-tfssecuritythe-ultimate-reference/)